# Using gmapping to build map and transport to the Non-ROS PC

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, follow-joint-trajectory, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS users,

Is it possible to use gmapping to build the map and transport the map to the Non-ROS computer?

To specify my question: I have a sick TiM 561 lidar(2D lidar) and I can launch it from the ROS package in the ubuntu 14.04LTS ROS

computer. Because I need to build the map to let my vehicle knows where is it and then do some vehicle dynamic suck as

obstacle avoidance and parking. Therefore,  I want to use the gmapping to build the maps and I want to transport the map

to the Non-ROS computer. But is it really possible to transport the map which is built by the gmapping to the Non-ROS

computer?  Does someone know? Could you give me some directions or suggestions. Thanks in advanced.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223439/using-gmapping-to-build-map-and-transport-to-the-non-ros-pc/) by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-01-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could use the map_saver in http://wiki.ros.org/map_server to convert the map into an image that can easily be copied to your non-ROS PC.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2016-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2016-01-04**:
Because the lidar transmits the distance data to my ROS computer. Can the map_saver collect all the data  of lidar and convert into the X,Y coordinate if the map? Thank you.

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-01-04**:
No it cannot. As it is clearly explained in the linked page...

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2016-01-05**:
@NEngelhard, I saw it and I think I need to change the title because I need to transport the map which is just 0 or 1 signal or x,y location of the object and then feed that to the Non-ROS computer which is the controller let a robot know can really know the environment. But thanks anyway really.